# What is the last step to use my scanner?

Tags: scanner

I have a Canon DR-1210C USB Scanner.

It is recognized by the kernel when plugged in:

```
[5365651.911506] usb 2-2.1: USB disconnect, address 3
[5365661.952066] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, address 2
[5365683.268060] usb 2-2: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 4
[5365683.441019] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1083, idProduct=160f
[5365683.441027] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[5365683.441033] usb 2-2: Product: CANON   DR-1210C        
[5365683.441037] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: CANON   
[5365683.441248] usb 2-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
```

`sane-find-scanner` can see it:

```
 # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x1083 [CANON   ], product=0x160f [CANON   DR-1210C        ], chip=GL845) at libusb:002:004
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x1083 [CANON   ], product=0x160f [CANON   DR-1210C        ], chip=GL845) at libusb:002:004
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

But `scanimage -L` says no scanner.

```
No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

So what is it that I have missed?
I tried following the HOWTO but it's not giving me any insight based on the troubleshooting advice.

Comment: It would be good to know which distro you try this on (for distro specific help/problems) and which HOWTO you followed (in case it is outdated, and so future readers that come here know that HOWTO might be incomplete)

Comment: I didn't keep a link to the HOWTO, but it was the first one I got from the google search.

Using debian 6.0.6

I gave up and installed Windows XP on a different machine.

Answer (score 1):

This is typical if the user that runs `scanimage` doesn't have rights to access the device. You can check which group the device belongs to using:

```
ls -la /dev/bus/usb/002/004
```

(the `002/004` part was taken from your `sane-find-scanner` output) and make sure that the user `saned` is member of the group owning the device. Make sure to restart the `saned` daemon after that change.

Comment: Gave up and installed on XP.
I'll come back to it if I have time.

Comment: @KenIngram I have some USB devices that are not supported under Linux (label printer e.g.) So I run them under WinXP in a VirtualBox VM (with USB extensions). If you don't already do that, and you have enough memory in your system you could give that a try. The VM could write the scanned images on a virtualbox share, directly accessible under Linux